# Выборка из бд 1 случайной записи, не работает ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Tags: mysql, запрос, случайные-числа

В бд есть 2 поста соответствующие этому запросу. Мне нужно случайно выбрать какой-то 1. Пробую в конце запроса добавить ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1, но всё равно выводится 2 записи. Почему так происходит, ведь должна оставаться 1 запись?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts 
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy USING(term_taxonomy_id)
  INNER JOIN wp_terms USING(term_id)
WHERE term_id='3878' AND post_status='publish' 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Не верю. Как это повторить? Возможно, ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: Запрос выводит все строки, LIMIT не срабатывает почему-то, когда таблицы соединены INNER JOINOM. http://storage5.static.itmages.com/i/17/1025/h_1508928350_9028349_8ff6463a63.jpeg

Comment: Проверьте в другом клиенте. Желательно в родном консольном `mysql`. Шибко умные клиенты могут делать в реальности не тот запрос, что вы написали. Пример бага, https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3539/ (возможно как раз ваша версия)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
Нужно до конца оформить второй и третий JOIN.

У них не указаны связки таблиц через ON.

Как-то так:

```
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON  wp_terms.id = term_id
```

Поэтому перебираются две таблицы wp_term_taxonomy и wp_terms . Получается M*N записей.

2)
Чтобы избежать кучи проблем, перечислите поля вместе с названиями таблиц в начале запроса

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, wp_terms.name AS tname 
-- и т.д.
```

Comment: `select fieldname from a join b using(fieldname)` это нормальное сокращение от `select a.fieldname from a join b on a.fieldname = b.fieldname`. (плюс обратите внимание на отсутствие грабли с обращением к не уникальному имени поля в select)